# Xcode cloud Swift Package Dependencies workspace does not exist at the root of the repository

Tags: xcode, cloud, matlab-spm

I send my project to Xcode cloud and I get this error

```
Xcode cloud Swift Package Dependencies workspace does not exist at the root of the repository
```

The project had cocoa pods, removed them and switched to spm.

Answer (score 3):

You just had to change the project in the diagram as shown in the screenshot below

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]